# Creating a mobile application for a specific device

Tags: android, mobile

I was looking to create a mobile application for [this handheld thermal printer](http://factory.dhgate.com/pdas/handheld-thermal-printer-terminal-equipment-with-camera-em200-p40114888.html) device.

This application is Win CE based. Does anyone know if there is a similar device with Android O.S(Having printer and barcode reader) ?

Comment: Are you going to attach a printer ? I was only referring to the barcode part.

Comment: @Reno: No ... The device itself has a printer. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

The sourcecode for the zxing project is open source and fairly simple to use, could that not work for what you want?

[Google code ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

As far as Im aware there aren't any devices such as that one, but it may happen later on down the line, if the manufacturers who sell those devices see Android as a viable / cost effective route to take (but this would involve losing all the investment in the windows CE platform)

Comment: I have found this, but i do not know if it works with Android mobiles or not : http://www.yourmobiledesk.com/products/proddetail.cfm?prodID=5052&catID=41&subcatID=na&sscatID=na&mfrID=na